# “syso” shortcut in Eclipse not working with lambda expression

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8, keyboard-shortcuts

In simple java code , “syso” shortcut  is working fine .
But when I am trying with lambda expression than “syso” shortcut is not working .

Example :-

> Not working

```
new Thread(()->syso).start();
```

> Working

```
new Thread(()->{
           syso
}).start();
```

Comment: that probably should be reported to Eclipse as a bug... It does not work for me either btw in the same scenario

Comment: Assuming you mean the "sysout" shortcut which is expanded to `System.out.println()` - this works for me. You might want to provide more information as it's hard to get what your specific problem is.

Comment: Yes if we use inside {}  than its work .But not work without {} .

Comment: @VijayGupta actually I am really annoyed by this also, thx for bringing this up. here is a bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515809. Let's see where it goes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=515809) in Eclipse, indeed. Thanks for reporting.

It has meanwhile been fixed, so this should work in the next [integration build](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/#4.7_Integration_Builds), or you may want to wait for either 4.7M7 or the 4.7 release (June).